# Program only seems to be reading every other line of .txt file

Tags: java, file-io

I'm working on an assignment in which I use scanners to read lines and tokens of a .txt file. I need to do some conversions and rearrange a few strings, which I have done using some helper methods. The problem is that the code is only working for every other line that it reads from the file. I think I may have messed something up somewhere in the beginning of the code. Any hints or tips on what I would need to modify? Here's what I have thusfar:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("PortlandWeather2013.txt"));
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String header = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(header);

        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(header);

        while (input2.hasNextLine()){
            String bottomHeader = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(bottomHeader);

            String dataLines = input.nextLine();

            Scanner linescan = new Scanner(dataLines);

            while (linescan.hasNext()){

                String station = linescan.next();
                System.out.print(station+ " ");

                String wrongdate = linescan.next();
                String year = wrongdate.substring(0,4) ;
                String day = wrongdate.substring(6);
                String month = wrongdate.substring(4,6);

                System.out.print(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);

                double prcp = linescan.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("\t  "+prcpConvert(prcp));

                double snwd = linescan.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("\t  " + snowConvert(snwd));

                double snow = linescan.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("\t" + snowConvert(snow));

                double tmax = linescan.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("\t" + tempConvert(tmax));

                double tmin = linescan.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("\t" + tempConvert(tmin));


            }

        }
    }
}

public static double prcpConvert(double x){

    double MM = x/1000;
    double In = MM * 0.039370;
    double rounded = Math.round(In * 10)/10;
    return rounded;


}
public static double snowConvert(double x){
    double In = x * 0.039370;
    double rounded = Math.round(In * 10)/10;

    return rounded;
}

public static double tempConvert(double x){
    double celsius = x/10;
    double fahrenheit = (celsius *9/5)+32;
    double rounded = Math.round(fahrenheit *10)/10;

    return rounded;
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new Scanner object for simple strings?

Comment: Also, please post the contents of PortlandWeather2013 and what your application is supposed to do. Without this information we can't help you out other than syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

`nextLine()` doesn't just fetch the last line, it also advances a line. Before your second loop you are calling `nextLine()` twice causing you to advance two lines each iteration of the loop.

You can fix your problem by setting `dataLines = bottomHeader` instead of calling `nextLine()` again.